# In middleman, create a dynamic URL in link_to?

Tags: middleman

I'm new to middleman and ruby so the syntax is very unfamiliar.
I have setup a simple list page and a dynamic article page.
This all works fine, but how do i generate the dynamic URL in link_to?

My list page is at localhost/list/
And my dynamic article page should be localhost/list/1/ where the number is dynamic.

```
<% data.list.each do |b| %>
    <%= link_to 'Read more', '/list/b.id.html' %>
<% end %>
```

How can I generate the dynamic URL?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to 'Read more', '/list/' + b.id.to_s + '.html' %>
```

Comment: This is a more Rubyish way: `<%= link_to 'Read more', "/list/#{b.id.to_s}.html" %>`.